# RDF: Extract value from type

Tags: prolog, rdf, owl

I have an `.owl` file which has an element something like this:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/kb/object_test.owl#obj_1234_pose">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.org/kb/example.owl#Transform"/>
    <example:quaternion rdf:datatype="http://example.org/kb/example.owl#vec4">0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0</example:quaternion>
    <example:translation rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#vec3">0.0 0.5 0.2</example:translation>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

When I do a `prolog` query (`triple` is part of the framework's query language):

```
triple('http://example.org/kb/object_test.owl#obj_1234_pose', 'http://example.org/kb/example.owl#translation', A).
```

I get the response:

```
type('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#vec3','0.0 0.5 0.2').
```

Firstly, I do not get `type` in the response when `rdf:datatype` is a `string`. In case of a string, I get the result as (for example): `0.0 0.5 0.2` Why is that so?

Secondly, is there any way to extract the value from the `type`? Or do I need to treat it a string manipulation?

Comment: Are you using SWI-Prolog? If so then you might have better luck at asking at the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)

Comment: which library do you use?